# How can I use the same CSS attribute on several selectors?

Tags: css

Please say there's a simpler/shorter way to write this CSS:

```
.ads h3{
color: #f7f7f7;
}
.ads p{
color: #f7f7f7;
}
.ads blockquote{
color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

It's a right pain at the moment and takes up space in the CSS file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### God says: *"Yes"*

*"Your prayers have been answered my child"*

```
.ads h3, .ads p, .ads blockquote {
    color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

And even taking it further (if there are no child elements which should *not* be colored as well):

```
.ads * {
    color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

And if you're OK with the text inside the paragraph itself to also have this same gray color:

```
.ads {
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

This will be overridden by any other styles that have been set on p, blockquote or h3, so you might want to take it further:

```
.ads, .ads * {
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the entertainment, but -1 because `.ads *` will still be overridden by `.ads h3` (and others), so it'll be useless. The universal selector `*` holds no value in terms of specificity. In other words, `.ads *` is specifically equivalent to `.ads`.

Comment: @BoltClock that's not quite right. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/4GqaF/ color gets overwritten. But thanks for the input

Comment: `.ads *` overrides `h3` because class is more specific than element so it wins out. If you change `h3` to `.ads h3` it overrides `.ads *`. See http://jsfiddle.net/JNPXm

Comment: yes, exactly. hmm, I see that I misread your comment. I thought you were saying that `.ads *` will get overridden by `h3`. sorry my bad. But you said two wrong things.. ".ads * is specifically equivelent to .ads" - that's not right because .ads * will color only the element inside of it, not the text within .ads, and you said that "* holds no value in terms of specifity" which is also not true.

Answer (score 7):

You can **group selectors** that you wish to share common rules by separating them with commas. So, the following will work:

```
.ads h3, .ads p, .ads blockquote {
   color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

See the [CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/), [Section 5.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are any other overriding rules you haven't shown, this will be fine:

```
.ads 
{
color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: Does not maintain equal specificity but if there are no other elements in `.ads` then this is fine. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this to make it simpler/shorter.

```
.ads h3, p, blockquotes{
color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ads h3, .ads p, .ads blockquote{
  color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ads h3,
.ads p,
.ads blockquote {
  color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the trailing `;` either (per [YUI CSS Min](http://www.phpied.com/yui-css-min-part-2/))

```
.ads h3,.ads p,.ads blockquote{color:#f7f7f7}
```

Comment: For development, sure.  If you're looking to reduce space, it's not needed.